# Passing data to executable file with PHP

Tags: c#, php

This is my PHP code for passing data to a C# exe file.

```
<?
    shell_exec("p3.exe --tRyMe");
?>
```

What I want is, I'll post a string to p3.exe file, and that exe file prints "tRyme" string to the screen.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a;
            Console.Write("Please enter a string : ");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered: {0}", a);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my C# code.

I've tried "--tRyMe", "-tRyMe", "tRyMe" etc. to do that but, this code prints only "Please enter a string" to the screen.

What I want is see the output like:

> You have entered:  tRyMe

Can you help me with doing that?
Best wishes.

Comment: I take it that you are new to `C#`; which is a good thing IMO. Everyone has to start somewhere! In your code, you are not reading anything from the `string[] args`. I am not a `C#` person, but logically that is an array of string, which you need to inspect first before you read `a` from user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't discuss the PHP code, but in the c# side, you need to check the number of arguments passed to your program from the command line and if there is an argument, don't ask for input, but print the argument received

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a;
        if(args.Length == 0)
        {
             Console.Write("Please enter a string : ");
             a = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
             a = args[0];

        Console.WriteLine("You have entered: {0}", a);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I was trying to do that for 3 hours :(

Answer (score 0):

Without having tried it, does a pipe work?

```
<?php
    shell_exec("echo tRyMe | p3.exe");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could only run an application and print the output but you can not interact with the application - Console.ReadLine() expects an input ...
so you can't use it (affects also Console.ReadKey())

try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a;
    if(args.Length == 0)
         a = "No arg is given";
    else
         a = args[0];

    Console.WriteLine("You have entered: {0}", a);
}
```